# PHP Filter array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, twitter, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I'm trying to filter the array output of GET search/tweets (remove tweets with empty 'geo' key and keep the tweets with 'geo' key) by using this piece of code.

```
$data = (array) $cb->search_tweets($params); //copy of raw print_r array here: http://pastebin.com/b2BvwUuJ

$filtered = array_filter($data, function($v) { 

    return $v['geo'] != 'false'; 

});

print_r($filtered);
```

It results in the following error code.

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results you have are not arrays, are objects. Change the comparison to this:

```
return $v->geo != 'false';
```

Comment: print_r is now giving me an empty Array (); as result using return $v->geo != '';. Could you explain why?

Comment: It's probably filtering them all. Are you sure you want to filter them with that condition? How do objects without `geo` look like? You may want to filter like `$v->geo != false` or `$v->geo != null`

Comment: I fixed it by myself. Using `$data['statuses']`